# Is there a proper way to evaluate against Python tuples?

Tags: python

I just caught an issue with something I wrote, and was hoping I could get a proper explanation of what was happening, and the best way to get around it. I have a fix in place, but am not sure if it's the best solution

I have a variable `interval` that is a string. In this scenario, let's say `interval = 'Day'`

Code compares this against a tuple in an `if` and `elif` expression:

```
if interval in ('FiscalWeekDaily','Daily'):
  ...
  ...
elif interval in ('DayHourly'):
```

Now I thought `'Day' in ('DayHourly')` would evaluate as `False` but it turns out it evaluates to `True`. What's the exact explanation for this? I would assume that since there is only 1 element, 'Day' is being compared against that element.

So if I try `'Day' in ('DayHourly', 'whatever')`, that evaluates as `False` because 'Day' is evaluated against each element, right?

So my fix is simply `elif interval in ['DayHourly']:`. Is that the proper way to go about doing this?

Comment: `('DayHourly')` is not a tuple. It's just `'DayHourly'`.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples with single objects in them need to have a comma, it is the *comma that makes the tuple, not the parentheses*.

In other words:

```
('DayHourly') == 'DayHourly'
```

You want `('DayHourly',)`